# Casting issue with ArrayList toArray() method

Tags: java, arrays

In one class I have constructor which looks like:

```
Class(int x, int y, int[] moves);
```

In other class which creates those objects I have moves stored in ArrayList. Moves are numbers. So when this class decides ti create new object it must first convert this ArrayList into array. So I tried something like this:

```
new Object(0, 0, (int[])moves.toArray(int[moves.size()]);
```

But it doesn't work. How should it be done properly?

Answer (score 5):

The result of calling `toArray()` on an `ArrayList` is *never* an `int[]`. You can't have an `ArrayList<int>` in Java due to the way generics works. At best it would be an `Integer[]`, which you'd then need to convert. Note that even though you can convert from `Integer` to `int`, you *can't* cast an `Integer[]` to an `int[]`. Something has to loop over the values.

You could just do it directly:

```
int[] values = new int[moves.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = moves.get(i);
}
```

Alternatively *could* create an `Integer[]` and then convert from that - but why do the copying twice?

Comment: No i don't want loop version. So you say it should look like: new Object(0, 0, (Integer[])moves.toArray(new Integer[moves.size()]) ?

Comment: @MichałTabor  guess you wouldn't need the cast , just `moves.toArray(new Integer[moves.size()]` would suffice .

Comment: @MichałTabor: Well that won't work because your constructor doesn't take an `Integer[]`, does it? *Something's* going to loop... given that you don't have the right types, it might as well be your code.