# parseDouble throwing NullPointerException for a non-null variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I would love to receive some help from second eyes, for I have struggled to identify what is wrong with my code.
In the Eclipse IDE I am attempting to implement a Google Maps activity that reads seaship MMSI codes from a file in the assets folder  (*/assets/mmsi.txt*) and adds maps markers to their respective locations. I am able to read from this file using the `BufferedReader` class but am having problems in converting the resulting `String` lines to double using the `Double.parseDouble` function.

LogCat detects the following problems.

```java
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.aquamet.saramap/com.aquamet.saramap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at com.aquamet.saramap.MainActivity.getMMSI(MainActivity.java:173)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at com.aquamet.saramap.MainActivity.setupRegion(MainActivity.java:136)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at com.aquamet.saramap.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:82)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3827)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
01-23 17:59:11.672: E/AndroidRuntime(18242):    ... 12 more
```

In other words, there seems to be a NullPointerException in the following code:

```java
private double[] getMMSI() throws IOException {
        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        double[] mmsi = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            InputStream  file_stream = am.open("mmsi.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file_stream));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String line;
        for (int i=0; (line = br.readLine()) != null; i++) {
                // Following line seems to be the problem (line 173).
                mmsi[i] = Double.parseDouble(line);
        }

        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But, while debugging the variable `line` is infact not null! (Sorry not enough REP for images)
[Debugging Screenshot](http://i45.tinypic.com/nnqfdz.png)

Another SO user had quite a similar problem, but his variables did seem to be badly initialized.
[parseDouble throwing Null Pointer in my code [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016634/parsedouble-throwing-null-pointer-in-my-code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble` isn't the problem. Your assignment is:

```
double[] mmsi = null;
...
// mssi is still null...
mmsi[i] = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

You never assign a non-null value to `mmsi`, hence the error when you try to write into it. If you want further proof of this, split your code into:

```
double tmp = Double.parseDouble(line);
mmsi[i] = tmp;
```

You'll see that the exception occurs on the *second* line, not the first.

Given that you don't know how many lines you'll need, I'd suggest you use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
List<Double> mmsi = new ArrayList<Double>();
...
mmsi.add(Double.valueOf(line));
```

EDIT: Additionally, you should be closing your file in a `finally` block. Currently, if an exception is thrown while you're reading, you leave the file open. And your current `catch` block implementations aren't as useful as just letting the exception be thrown, IMO.

Comment: Sorry Perl programmer here, but totally makes sense. Your solution though seems to be much more elegant than using a fixed sized double array.

I want to avoid breaking the rest of my code though, so I'm afraid I will have to pre-process the file to find out how many lines I need.

Comment: @jhc: Why? You can always create the array *after* parsing all the values into an `ArrayList`, then copy them from the list to the array. That's cleaner than reading the file twice.

Comment: I guess I could simply convert from the list to a normal array afterwords.
Would this be correct?
    Double[] mmsi = new Double[list.size()];
    list.toArray(mmsi);

Comment: @jhc: That would create a `Double[]` array instead of a `double[]`. Unfortunately I don't believe there's anything built-in which will do that in one go. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483243/casting-issue-with-arraylist-toarray-method/14483291#14483291 for a similar situation with `int`/`Integer`.

Comment: I implemented the ArrayList, and the app works well! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with: `double[] mmsi = null;`

You have not created your array.

Try:

```
double[] mmsi = new double[10]; // or your desired array size
```

More info about arrays: [Arrays in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: This makes alot of sense. I'll need to pre-process the file though to figure out how large I want my array.

Answer (score 1):

The array of doubles mmsi is never initialized to reference some thing apart from null reference. Hence the NPE

```
 double[] mmsi = null;
```